# web application - structured data in an word like editor

Tags: angular, web, web-applications

I am looking for a way to capture structured data in a document, but the capture should be as fluid as possible (without separate fields) - like in a word document with the expandable sections when using headings. Is there a possibility to realize something like that in a webapplication (e.g. with angular)? I have already found some information about realized text editors with angular, but no information about such expandable areas. But maybe there is a better idea? In the end it should be possible to query for example the content from laboatory and treatment individually.

[image]